# Typescript trait implementation

Tags: typescript, traits

I have found many examples of traits and mixins in typescript, but I miss the way to access public trait method inside the class using the trait
Is there a way to have compilator valid trait complete implementation?

```js
class A {
  methA() {}
}

class B {
  methB(){}
}

class C extends B { // and things like "use A"
  methC() {
    this.methA()+this.methB()
  }
}
car c = new C
c.methA()+c.methB()==c.methC()
```

I tried with an ugly `Object.assign(this, new A)` but TSC doesn't detect it.

Comment: This is called aspect-oriented programming. JavaScript (and TypeScript) do not support AOP.

Comment: There's no `Object.this(…)` in standard library.

Comment: Typescript has no traits at all. What you're using is inheritance.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Sorry I wrote a mistale… I edited it…

Comment: @Alejandro I want C extends A and B…

Comment: @Justinas That gives me a lot of clue ! (still searching the answer that fits my case). Thanks !